# Call and get response from web api in a winform c# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest, api

I am making a simple WinForm Application in Windows and I want to get some data about foreign exchange rates. So I decided to call an API from Oanda. I tried several things around but nothing worked. It gives the response in CSV as well as JSON format. I don't know which will be easier to handle.

Also for this type of response, I am unable to create its model class. 
Response:

JSON:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "effective_params": {
      "data_set": "OANDA",
      "base_currencies": [
        "EUR"
      ],
      "quote_currencies": [
        "USD"
      ]
    },
    "endpoint": "spot",
    "request_time": "2019-06-08T12:05:23+00:00",
    "skipped_currency_pairs": []
  },
  "quotes": [
    {
      "base_currency": "EUR",
      "quote_currency": "USD",
      "bid": "1.13287",
      "ask": "1.13384",
      "midpoint": "1.13336"
    }
  ]
}
```

CSV:

```
base_currency,quote_currency,bid,ask,midpoint
EUR,USD,1.13287,1.13384,1.13336
```

I just need those three numbers so, which method will be helpful and how.

This code I already tried:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www1.oanda.com/rates/api/v2/rates/");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("spot.csv?api_key=<myapikey>&base=EUR&quote=USD");
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
textBox1.Text = result;
```

Edit: I need the result of this call for my further processing so I must need this method to complete its execution before proceeding further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First creating model from Json:

1. use a online model generator like [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com), for the Json that you have posted, following is the model generated:

   ```
   public class EffectiveParams
   {
     public string data_set { get; set; }
     public List<string> base_currencies { get; set; }
     public List<string> quote_currencies { get; set; }
   }

   public class Meta
   {
     public EffectiveParams effective_params { get; set; }
     public string endpoint { get; set; }
     public DateTime request_time { get; set; }
     public List<object> skipped_currency_pairs { get; set; }
   }

   public class Quote
   {
     public string base_currency { get; set; }
     public string quote_currency { get; set; }
     public string bid { get; set; }
     public string ask { get; set; }
     public string midpoint { get; set; }
   }

   public class RootObject
   {
     public Meta meta { get; set; }
     public List<Quote> quotes { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Now connecting to the `WebAPI` using `HttpClient`, which has the option to return both `Json` and `CSV`, I would prefer `JSON` being standard, which can also be consumed easily by variety of clients, use the following simple generic methods:

> Assuming it is GET only call, just supply the Host and API details to the generic Process method underneath:

```
public async Task<TResponse> Process<TResponse>(string host,string api)
{
   // Execute Api call Async
   var httpResponseMessage = await MakeApiCall(host,api);

   // Process Json string result to fetch final deserialized model
   return await FetchResult<TResponse>(httpResponseMessage);
} 

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeApiCall(string host,string api)

{   
    // Create HttpClient
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }) { BaseAddress = new Uri(host) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Make an API call and receive HttpResponseMessage
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(api, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

    return responseMessage;
}

public async Task<T> FetchResult<T>(HttpResponseMessage result)
{
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Convert the HttpResponseMessage to string
        var resultArray = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Json.Net Deserialization
        var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultArray);

        return final;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

> How to use:

- Simply call:

  ```
  var rootObj = await Process<RootObject>("https://www1.oanda.com/rates/", "api/v2/rates/");
  ```
- You receive the deserialized `RootObject` as shown in the model above
- For anything further complex processing like sending input to the call with http body, above generic code needs further modification, it is currently only specific to your requirement

**Edit 1: (Making the entry call Synchronous)**

- To make the overall call synchronous, use the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at the topmost level, Main method will be converted to, rest all will remain same as in the sample (async methods)

  ```
    void Main()
    {
       var rootObj =  Process<RootObject>("https://www1.oanda.com/rates/", "api/v2/rates/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
  ```

**Edit 2: (Making complete code Synchronous)**

```
void Main()
{
    var rootObj = Process<RootObject>("https://www1.oanda.com/rates/", "api/v2/rates/");
}


public TResponse Process<TResponse>(string host, string api)
{
    // Execute Api call
    var httpResponseMessage = MakeApiCall(host, api);

    // Process Json string result to fetch final deserialized model
    return FetchResult<TResponse>(httpResponseMessage);
}

public HttpResponseMessage MakeApiCall(string host, string api)

{
    // Create HttpClient
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }) { BaseAddress = new Uri(host) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // Make an API call and receive HttpResponseMessage
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync(api, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return responseMessage;
}

public T FetchResult<T>(HttpResponseMessage result)
{
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Convert the HttpResponseMessage to string
        var resultArray = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Json.Net Deserialization
        var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultArray);

        return final;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: A couple of things: `Quote.bid/ask/midpoint` should be defined as `decimal`. `Meta.request_time` should really be deserialize to `DateTimeOffset` (in the current scenario there's no offset (`+0`), but as a general rule...). For the rest it's good, IMO (since now you have converted it to .Net :). Someone may point out that, since you're using Tasks, `HttpClient` should be static. It'll work anyway.

Comment: Btw, isn't if fascinating that, in the full framework, `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application` doesn't - as of `.Net 4.8` - include `Json` as Mime type, while it's available in .Net Core since `2.1` and `.Net Standard 2.1`?

Comment: I am getting an error with this. The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. I know we already did that method async still I am getting this error. IDE: Visual Studio Community 2019 edition.

Comment: @Inv3nt0r that's a genuine error, which simply suggest that either you have not marked the function as `async` or you are not returning `Task<T>`, ideal would be that you edit your question and provide the details. For Async methods, you need to ensure that complete chain including the entry is marked Async, you shal not `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` anywhere. On other note you may even make complete chain Non Async and that would also work fine but a blocking call for a thread

Comment: @Jimi set of valid point regarding model, it is actually generated based on json sample provided, though I concur with you in terms of ideal data Type. Regarding point related to Task and static HttpClient, I am not sure if I understood it well. Not including Json as default Mime type is indeed baffling, again I concur. Thanks for valid inputs.

Comment: @Inv3nt0r my guess is you are not making entry point for the call to the `Process<RootObject>` as Async, this is how it should be,

`async Task Main()`
`{`
 `await Process<RootObject>("https://www1.oanda.com/rates/", "api/v2/rates/");`
`}`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Well, I am not used to asynchronous programming. Right now I need the result of this call for my further processing so I must need this method to complete its execution before proceeding further. I tried writing the call in async method and just called that method and error turned into a warning. I edited my question regarding the same. First I tried and did get a response. But now It is throwing NullReferenceException!

Comment: @Inv3nt0r these issue are primarily there due to incorrect API usage, difficult to know without reviewing some code, in this case `HttpClient` only offers `GetAsync` method, as a simple solution what i would recommend is remove async, await everywhere, make all methods synchronous and for `GetAsync` call use the following code:

`HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync(api, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;`

This is a blocking code, which will wait for API call to complete

Comment: About *Task and static HttpClient*: this is use-case scenario specific. As you know `HttpClient` is designed to be used as a singleton (initialized `static` or `static` `Lazy<HttpClient>`). The use of Task could imply that the HttpClient class is used frequently. Since HttpClient (as, of course, WebRequest, WebClient etc.) don't manage their connections (function delegated to the ServicePointManager), creating/destroying an HttpClient object doesn't release the underlying connection, hold by one or more `ServicePoint`. Frequent requests can drain the available connections relatively quickly.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I tried what you mentioned and it didn't work. I want it synchronous, I must need tha values for further processing. Can you please edit your answer and give an sample code for such use case.

Comment: @Inv3nt0r, check the two edits **Edit1** and **Edit2**, where I have shown how to make just entry point synchronous and how to make whole implementation synchronous, idea remains instead of  `await` we use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, thus makes the calls synchronous, though this would surely have the scalability impact

Comment: Thank you so much @MrinalKamboj it worked really well. Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an online service such as [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to get your json model and [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialise and deserialise the json string. The following models your json.

```
public class EffectiveParams
{
    public string data_set { get; set; }
    public List<string> base_currencies { get; set; }
    public List<string> quote_currencies { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public EffectiveParams effective_params { get; set; }
    public string endpoint { get; set; }
    public DateTime request_time { get; set; }
    public List<object> skipped_currency_pairs { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public string base_currency { get; set; }
    public string quote_currency { get; set; }
    public string bid { get; set; }
    public string ask { get; set; }
    public string midpoint { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Quote> quotes { get; set; }
}
```

Note that you can change `RootOject` to a more descriptive name.

So, for example, to get the *bid, ask and midpoint* value for each `quotes`, you can simply do this:

```
RootObject rootObj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

//Get the required values.
foreach(var quote in rootObj.quotes)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Bid : {quote.bid} Ask: {quote.ask} MidPoint: {quote.midpoint}");
}
```

Comment: `var quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString).quotes.First();` or `var quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString).quotes` then `foreach (var q in quotes) { ... }`

Comment: @Jimi I know that. It's just an example to show how things work.

Comment: Well, there's no harm in making it a working example, then.

Comment: @bolkay Thank you soo much for the answers. It worked really well.